# How to recycle unity scroll list of game objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollrect

In my game, I have a scrollrect which its content have a VerticalLayout component. When I fill that with so many count of GameObjects, the game will fall in problem!

My list has more than 300 GameObjects.

How to optimize my scroll list?

Comment: "*the game will fall in problem*" you need to be more specific about how it is failing for us to be able to help you fix it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain a list with more than 300 game objects will cause leak memory. I have to create just game objects that show in pane and simulate scroll, but i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please show the proof that you found that putting 300 objects in the list causes a leak [as a edit to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38795637/edit)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Memory leak is happen in android and ios devices. In windows there is no problem.

Comment: Again, **show your proof**. For example [you can attach the profiler to an android or iOS device](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) and show the leak happening there. Take a screenshot and put it in your question. Without it you are unlikely to get any answers.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain [This is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOQV8AA50Rw) my problem and what I want to know

Comment: That is not a memory leak, that is a performance issue from having many objects. Why don't you do what the video says and pay the $5 and download [the asset package](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/58158) that does it for you.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Because its a dll and I don't know Is it work for me or not!

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem (Performance issue, as [Scott Chamberlain said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38795637/how-to-recycle-unity-scroll-list-of-game-objects/38798169?noredirect=1#comment64966314_38795637)) by do some tips in [Optimising Unity new UI System Article](https://gamedevresources.blogspot.nl/2015/05/optimising-unity-new-ui-system.html).

Disabling pixel perfect is very useful tip that works for me:

> - ScrollRect will rebuild / reload everything every frame if pixel
>     perfect is enabled.
> - Canvas PixelPerfect has large performance impact. Disable it if possible.

Another useful tip:

> - Disable gameobject when off-screen